# Compare NSString with bunch of regex

Tags: objective-c, regex, nsregularexpression

This case is different I think, I have a word and I have some 100 regex with me. I want to check which regex it is passing? How to do it in an optimised way?

Comment: We can merge regexes using `|` (pipe) delimiter, but you should better check this in a loop otherwise it is expected to work slower.

Comment: @NeverHopeless, Thank you for your valuable suggestion. I'm more interested in the regex pattern it matches and how to get which regex pattern it matches using the | (pipe) symbol?

Comment: @Arock I don't see where's the problem ? Can't you just loop through the regexes and try them all, if it succeeds then print it out for example ?

Comment: @HamZa, I can't loop through 200 regex pattern for every single character I type in. I feel it is inefficient to do so. Is there a way to classify the regex in order to minimize the comparison? That is my qn.

Comment: @Arock Then your question is unclear, you didn't mention that you need to match several times. But let's think logically: you have 1 string, according to what you have said, you want to check **all** regexes if they match that string or not. Now tell me: how in the world can you optimise it if you need to try them **all** ? `Try them all == loop`

Comment: using pipe you can do like this: "regex1|regex2|regex3....|regexn". Remember the greater the number of regexes the more slower it will be. Also, You can NOT find which of them matched your sample string.

Answer (score 0):

The most efficient way would be to combine all of those regular expressions into a deterministic finite automaton (a finite state machine). Then run the string through that finite state machine.

[Michael Sipser's Introduction to the Theory of Computation](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/113318779X) explains how to do this. It is fairly complex, thus the reference to the book.

After you have constructed the DFA by hand, you can implement it in code.

There are tools that can do this for you, such as [flex](https://github.com/westes/flex/). flex takes the regular expressions as input and generates the DFA as .c file which you can then use in your project. You can configure flex to return a token to indicate which regular expression was matched.

flex is a unix tool and is part of OS X 10.8.